# accountExpires attribute not listed when read from Java

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap

Hello Java and AD experts..

I am having an issue while reading accountExpires attribute value from AD. When I read this attribute using Java code, I got the result null.

Then I thought of checking various attributes provided by AD by printing the all the AD attributes using the following code:

```
        Attributes allAttrs = ldapCtx.getAttributes(distinguishedName);
        System.out.println("Total no.of properties: " + allAttrs.size());
        try{
            String attrs = "";
            for (NamingEnumeration ae = allAttrs.getAll(); ae.hasMore();) {
                Attribute attr = (Attribute) ae.next();
                attrs = attrs+"\nFor attribute: "+ attr.getID()+" values are - ";


                /* print each value */
                for (NamingEnumeration e = attr.getAll(); e.hasMore(); attrs = attrs + e.next()+";");

            }
            System.out.println(attrs);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Exception in getAttribute: " + e);
        }
```

It had listed 72 properties. And accountExpires property itself is not present there :(

Can anyone guide me why this property is not available in my case and how to get rid of this

Regards,
FH

Answer (score 0):

It wont list any account expiration attribute. You need to calculate it. Suppose your password expiration limit is 90 days and you need to send a warning mail to the user when there is 10 days left for expiration. You will get account created date, find the number of days between the account created date and current date if the difference is 80 then send a warning mail.

Comment: HI Anoop,Thanks for your reply.
In fact, I am looking for the value which is listed in AD -> Accounts tab -> Account Expires section -> End of (This is a radio button with 2 options: Never and End Of. For the concerned user, it is selected as End Of and the date is mentioned as Friday, June 16, 2017. I want to read this value from AD)

I hope you got what I am trying to read here. I don't know how to share an image here, else I would have shared the screen cap of my AD.

Comment: Hi Anoop,

To be very specific, I want to read the Account validity expiry date (listed in Accounts tab -> Account Expires section -> End of). And not the password expiry date.